# VS Code remote debugging python (VS Code must be server)

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I'm trying to use the VS Code remote debug feature (debugpy).

My problem is that my code to connect needs to be the client and VS Code needs to be the server.
Why? Because I can't modify the command line of my python "container" (It's an embedded version of python into another process). So I simply want to execute a command in my py code, which, then, connects to my debug server that has been startet in VS Code.
Is that possible? I know that this works in PyCharm professional, but I can't get it done in VS Code.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? I have a very similar situation and would be extremely interested if so.

Comment: Unfortunately not